# how to pass column name of tables to a function in a loop to perform calculation on each column data separately?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have a pivot table in SQL and I want to perform same calculation on each column of table separately. How do I achieve that.
Say, table has columnA,columnB,columnc,columnD
I want to get 10th largest values from all columns and put them in a table. How do I achieve it?

I want to find 10th smallest value for all strategies,
and then store these values in a separate table with same headers.

I have no problem calculating the values. Just confused in how to pass columns in a loop to the function.

Sample Data:

| StrategyA | StrategyB | StrategyC | StrategyD | StrategyE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4473.164519 | -832204.0006 | 25095.16851 | 8788977.725 | 506105.7806 |
| -222508.8221 | -851761.6503 | 164218.3626 | -4367196.053 | -84624.36628 |
| 867003.7236 | 487008.4025 | 26710.88107 | 4082241.97 | 189234.9322 |
| -330435.2971 | 365190.5616 | -10584.46692 | 4102757.782 | 299020.0012 |
| -535310.2508 | 310416.7992 | 79897.24744 | -10953293.61 | -564989.8894 |
| -514024.1552 | -346664.9571 | 55618.36525 | 8522229.45 | 655242.7607 |
| -436928.7429 | -58154.95719 | -44987.25771 | 5425344.541 | 35985.08909 |
| -6464.566909 | -360774.5086 | 53418.19191 | 14460736.71 | 245481.6733 |
| 1263647.387 | 276284.247 | 71139.91947 | -2261400.941 | 43325.73506 |
| 585130.213 | 175584.3894 | 48335.7496 | 8522351.461 | -318176.6566 |
| 345966.5601 | 84640.05185 | 878.7445104 | -8279378.739 | 131650.8008 |
| -1014561.295 | -60904.16851 | 49445.97807 | 5949547.396 | -100504.8712 |
| -296675.3075 | -54446.86927 | 24695.90471 | -4290511.847 | 163124.7882 |
| -393639.2875 | -298330.2819 | 46869.02256 | 8260696.205 | 616997.3033 |
| 170574.9289 | 1443.363565 | 43365.57016 | -4090479.985 | -137358.3613 |
| 6742.101683 | 15065.29802 | 12467.78135 | -3110231.995 | -155413.7505 |
| 73421.38876 | 25301.92932 | 24400.89382 | -1907483.704 | 217638.5604 |

Expected:
a table with same columns but only 10th smallest value of each column:

| StrategyA | StrategyB | StrategyC | StrategyD | StrategyE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -6464.566909 | 1443.363565 | 43365.57016 | 4082241.97 | 131650.8008 |

Comment: Sample data, expected results, and your attempts will help us help you. This is pretty vague as it stands.

Comment: *"Just confused in how to pass columns in a loop to the function."* What do you mean by this? Why do you want to use a loop, when SQL is a set based language?

Comment: You can do this with a single query. If you post sample data and expected results as text [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)
 someone could show you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by assigning a `row_number` for each column, then selecting each using a `case expression`

```
with x as (
    Row_Number() over(order by StrategyA) r1, 
    Row_Number() over(order by StrategyB) r2, 
    Row_Number() over(order by StrategyC) r3,
    Row_Number() over(order by StrategyD) r4,
    Row_Number() over(order by StrategyE) r5
    from t
)
select 
    max(case when r1=10 then StrategyA end) StrategyA,
    max(case when r2=10 then StrategyB end) StrategyB,
    max(case when r3=10 then StrategyC end) StrategyC,
    max(case when r4=10 then StrategyD end) StrategyD,
    max(case when r5=10 then StrategyE end) StrategyE
from x
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Stu, but what if the strategies are dynamic, there could be more or less strategies given the situation.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by dynamic - do you mean you are adding or dropping columns from the same table? If so that sounds like a bad design decision and would require the use of `dynamic sql` to build the query by querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` -the end result though would be the same basic logic.

Comment: Considering you state, however, you want to do this in a `FUNCTION` though, then you **can't** use dynamic SQL. If that is the case this sounds like an XY Problem, @VijayMadhani .

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't both with window functions:

```
select (select strategyA from t order by strategyA offset 9 row fetch first 1 row only),
       (select strategyB from t order by strategyB offset 9 row fetch first 1 row only),
       (select strategyC from t order by strategyC offset 9 row fetch first 1 row only),
       (select strategyD from t order by strategyD offset 9 row fetch first 1 row only),
       (select strategyE from t order by strategyE offset 9 row fetch first 1 row only)
```

As for making this dynamic, I would do that *before* pivoting and put the values in separate rows.

```
select u.*
from (select u.*,
             row_number() over (partition by strategyType order by strategyValue) as seqnum
      from unpivoted u
     ) u
where seqnum = 1;
```